# Porque não ganho Inquisitive bage , tenho 31/30 perguntas certas?

Tags: support, badges

Porque não ganho  Inquisitive bage , tenho 31/30 perguntas certas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I hope you don't mind me answering in English...)

You can click on the 'Inquisitive' label in your [profile](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/1519/clmend?tab=topactivity), and the popup shows that while you did satisfy the requirement to ask a positively received question on at least 30 days, you still need a so-called 'positive question record':

[image]

The [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/295232) tells what that means:

> In order to qualify for any of these badges, you must have a "positive question record", which means you don't have too many Closed, Negative, or Deleted questions overall. The formula is `(TotalQuestions - Negative - Closed - Deleted) / TotalQuestions ≥ 0.5`.

Comment: Wat! Black magic, that you would _without a noticeable reason_ :) notice this and answer.

Comment: What s  a positive question record, in this topic?

Comment: @ClMend that's explained in the linked post. If I look at your profile, I only see two questions with score -1, so you must have quite a few deleted ones.

Comment: i need to close and delet questions.? thank you

Comment: @ClMend No, absolutely not; closed and deleted questions count double against your question record. You need to ask **more** well-received questions (positive score, not closed) and simultaneously not (too many) new questions which are closed/deleted/downvoted.

Comment: The formula shwold be automatic .  then i could no how many questions needed

Comment: The formula **is** automatic... it's right there in this answer: `(TotalQuestions - Negative - Closed - Deleted) / TotalQuestions ≥ 0.5`. The formula is fair in its neutrality, but you might have some difficulty offsetting the weight of your several deleted questions, @ClMend .

Comment: Only a place like SE makes one's own deletions count against oneself. What BS. "asked a well-received question on 30 separate qualifying days" Huh? That's really impossible to understand.